# How do I find the most frequent element in a list in pyspark?

Tags: list, pyspark, frequency

I have a pyspark dataframe with two columns, ID and Elements. Column "Elements" has list element in it. It looks like this,

```
ID | Elements
_______________________________________
X  |[Element5, Element1, Element5]
Y  |[Element Unknown, Element Unknown, Element_Z]
```

I want to form a column with the most frequent element in the column 'Elements.' Output should look like,

```
ID | Elements                                           | Output_column 
__________________________________________________________________________
X  |[Element5, Element1, Element5]                      | Element5
Y  |[Element Unknown, Element Unknown, Element_Z]       | Element Unknown
```

How can I do that using pyspark?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

We can use higher order functions here (available from spark 2.4+)

1. First use `transform` and `aggregate` to get counts for each distinct value in the array.
2. Then sort the array of structs in descending manner and then get the first element.

---

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
temp = (df.withColumn("Dist",F.array_distinct("Elements"))
              .withColumn("Counts",F.expr("""transform(Dist,x->
                           aggregate(Elements,0,(acc,y)-> IF (y=x, acc+1,acc))
                                      )"""))
              .withColumn("Map",F.arrays_zip("Dist","Counts")
              )).drop("Dist","Counts")
out = temp.withColumn("Output_column",
                    F.expr("""element_at(array_sort(Map,(first,second)->
         CASE WHEN first['Counts']>second['Counts'] THEN -1 ELSE 1 END),1)['Dist']"""))
```

---

**Output:**

*Note that I have added a blank array for ID z to test. Also you can drop the column `Map` by adding `.drop("Map")` to the output*

```
out.show(truncate=False)

+---+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+
|ID |Elements                                     |Map                                   |Output_column  |
+---+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+
|X  |[Element5, Element1, Element5]               |[{Element5, 2}, {Element1, 1}]        |Element5       |
|Y  |[Element Unknown, Element Unknown, Element_Z]|[{Element Unknown, 2}, {Element_Z, 1}]|Element Unknown|
|Z  |[]                                           |[]                                    |null           |
+---+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+
```

---

For lower versions, you can use a udf with statistics mode:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F,types as T
from statistics import mode
u = F.udf(lambda x: mode(x) if len(x)>0 else None,T.StringType())

df.withColumn("Output",u("Elements")).show(truncate=False)
+---+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
|ID |Elements                                     |Output         |
+---+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
|X  |[Element5, Element1, Element5]               |Element5       |
|Y  |[Element Unknown, Element Unknown, Element_Z]|Element Unknown|
|Z  |[]                                           |null           |
+---+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyspark sql functions to achieve that (spark 2.4+).
Here is a generic function that adds a new column containing the most common element in another array column. Here it is:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

def add_most_common_val_in_array(df, arraycol, drop=False):
    """Takes a spark df column of ArrayType() and returns the most common element
    in the array in a new column of the df called f"MostCommon_{arraycol}"

    Args:
        df (spark.DataFrame): dataframe
        arraycol (ArrayType()): array column in which you want to find the most common element
        drop (bool, optional): Drop the arraycol after finding most common element. Defaults to False.

    Returns:
        spark.DataFrame: df with additional column containing most common element in arraycol
    """
    dvals = f"distinct_{arraycol}"
    dvalscount = f"distinct_{arraycol}_count"
    startcols = df.columns
    df = df.withColumn(dvals, sf.array_distinct(arraycol))
    df = df.withColumn(
        dvalscount,
        sf.transform(
            dvals,
            lambda uval: sf.aggregate(
                arraycol,
                sf.lit(0),
                lambda acc, entry: sf.when(entry == uval, acc + 1).otherwise(acc),
            ),
        ),
    )
    countercol = f"ReverseCounter{arraycol}"
    df = df.withColumn(countercol, sf.map_from_arrays(dvalscount, dvals))
    mccol = f"MostCommon_{arraycol}"
    df = df.withColumn(mccol, sf.element_at(countercol, sf.array_max(dvalscount)))
    df = df.select(*startcols, mccol)
    if drop:
        df = df.drop(arraycol)
    return df
```